# How can I assign a current var to else statement to be able to compare the var value and then save it to get a result?

Tags: c#, return-value, variable-assignment, store, min

I have a If Else statement to get nearest station from the current one that means first nearest station is null(does not exist) and second station is calculated based on min distance of the first one. In Else part, I am comparing current station's distance with known min distance by using Math.Min. However, I am missing to store the result and to assign the current station in the Else statement. The place of my issue is the line 14 and 15.

```
class City : ICity
    {
        private List<Company> _companies;
        private List<Line> _lines;
        private List<Station> _stations;
        internal City(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            _companies = new List<Company>();
            _lines = new List<Line>();
            _stations = new List<Station>();
        }
        public string Name{get;}
        public ILine AddLine(string name){...} 
        public IStation AddStation(string name, int x, int y){...}

        public IStation FindNearestStation(int x, int y)
        {
            int ? minDist = null;
            Station minStation=null;
            foreach (var station in _stations)
            {
                int dis = GetDistancebtween(x1: station.X, y1: station.Y, x2: x, y2: y);
                if (!minDist.HasValue || dis < minDist.Value)
                {
                    minDist = dis;
                    minStation = station;
                }
            }
            return minStation;            
        }

        private int GetDistancebtween(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        {
            return (x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2; 

        }            
}
```

The unit test breaks on the line 10.

```
public void city_returns_effectively_the_closest_station()
{
    ICity c = CityFactory.CreateCity("Paris");

    IStation s = c.AddStation("Opera", 0, 0);
    IStation s1 = c.AddStation("Chatelet", 10, 10);

    c.FindNearestStation(-10, -10).Should().BeSameAs(s);
    //test does not pass in this position
    c.FindNearestStation(10, 10).Should().BeSameAs(s1);
    c.FindNearestStation(15, 15).Should().BeSameAs(s1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the minDist value then you should also change the minStation value. Using a simple if inside the else block instead of Math.Min should resolve the problem.

```
....
else
{
    if(dis < minDist.Value)
    {
        minDist = dis;
        minStation = station;
    }
}
```

and this leads to this further change without using an else block

```
foreach (var station in _stations)
{
    var dis = GetDistancebtween(x1: x, y1: y, x2: station.X, y2: station.Y);
    if(!minDist.HasValue || dis < minDist.Value)
    {
        minDist = dis;
        minStation = station;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still breaks at the same level of the Unit test on the line 9 so a bit sooner.

Comment: Could you add the code for _GetDistancebtween_? The 0,0 should be at the same distance for -10,-10 and 10,10 but it doesn't seem to be so. Also the internal _stations_ variable is a list right?

Comment: The information that might be crucial. The function findNearestStation is in the class City that has an ICity interface. The function when I calculate distance is this function: ``` private int GetDistancebtween(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        {
            return (x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2; 
        } ``` Rest of the information I added in my question.

Comment: Not sure about it, but a quick search for the nearest point formula is not as you have written it. If I use your formula with your data I get (added Console.WriteLine inside FindNearestStation 1st: _Name=Opera - Distance=4
Name=Chatelet - Distance=0
Found = Chatelet_ 2nd: 
_Name=Opera - Distance=12
Name=Chatelet - Distance=0
Found = Chatelet_ 3rd: 
_Name=Opera - Distance=0
Name=Chatelet - Distance=4
Found = Opera_

Comment: You mean when you do the manual test and put the values of the unit test in the else statement or in the function getDistanceBetween?

Comment: Here your example reworked for direct test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TnxkMs

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out :)

Comment: Is this the correct formula? Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((x1 - x2),2) + Math.Pow((y1 - y2),2));

Comment: This one yes but mine not.